# Numbers greater than average (steamreader)

Tags: c#

I have been able to create a method that looks in a specific textfile and manages to print the biggest, the smallest and the average numbers located in this file.

I've used the following codestring;

```
var average = File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).Average();
return average;
```

However I have not found any methods that can look in the textfile and print the numbers that are greater than average. If someone would give me some valuable pointers I would really appreciate it.
My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declare textfile

            string textFile;

            //read the textfile

            StreamReader fromFile = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");

            //calculate the result

            int biggestNumber = readBiggest(fromFile);
            int smallestNumber = readSmallest(fromFile);
            double average = readAverage(fromFile);

            //ask user to save the result in a textfile of his choice
            Console.WriteLine("Files from test.txt has been gathered...");

            textFile = userInput("Enter the filename that you wish to store the result in: ");
            StreamWriter toFile = new StreamWriter(textFile);            

            //present the result

            toFile.WriteLine("The greatest number is {0}, {1} is the smallest number. The average number is {2}", biggestNumber, smallestNumber, average);
            toFile.Close();
        }


        private static double readAverage(StreamReader fromFile)
        {
            var average = File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).Average();
            return average;
        }

        private static int readBiggest(StreamReader fromFile)
        {
            var max = File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).Max();
            return max;
        }
        private static int readSmallest(StreamReader fromFile)
        {
            var min = File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).Min();
            return min;
        }

        private static string userInput(string nameOfTextFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameOfTextFile);
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT read from the file 3 times just to work out the average, max and min. Read the data in once and work with the same list in memory.

Comment: If you can iterate several times, you could use `.Where(x >= average)` as another pass. Note that this might not works as desired due to rounding errors of `average`.

Comment: Why do all your methods ignore the `fromFile` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - DO NOT read the file 3 times. Reading from the file on disk is going to be the slowest part of your whole program and doing it 3 times just makes that 3 times worse. Read it once:

```
var numbers = File.ReadLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Note: if you want to have that value available to multiple class methods, just assign it to a private field.

Now use that multiple times.

```
var average = numbers.Average();
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
```

To get just the numbers > average, just calculate the average first, and then use it in a `Where`:

```
var greaterThanAverage = numbers.Where(x => x > average);
```

And then you can just iterate through that and print them:

```
foreach (var num in greaterThanAverage) 
{
    Console.Writeline(num.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `File.ReadLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).ToList()` that way you only need to store the integers, not the strings and you don't need to parse them for each enumeration.

Comment: Good point. Deferred execution can some times bite you in the butt without realizing it. Added the `ToList` part.

Comment: Chain a `ToList()` after mapping to `int.Parse`. Otherwise, the average, min, max functions will each ReadAllLines and Parse.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 They will only read the file once, since `ReadAllLines` returns an array. If you enumerate only once, `ReadLines` may be a better choice since it leads to lower memory pressure (but for small files it doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var avg = data.Average();
var gavg = data.Where(o=>o>avg).ToList();
```